# Sql update textbox not showing db information

Tags: c#, sql, web-application-design

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
using SQL.Server.Management.Studio.2008.R2;
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is update a sql database..
I'm stuck at this step.. I've got my webpage to print the sqldatabase content into a div.. Right now, I'm trying to put some content into a textbox. But whenever I debug, it's throwing me this error. [image: The error I am getting]
Stuck at this part, please shine some light on my situation.
Also.. Am I going the right way with this? Is there a more effective method of doing this? Opinions and links to good tutorials/walkthroughs would be appreciated too! Thanks in advance.
My html

```
<input runat="server" class="hexen" id="investigate1"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate2"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate3"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate4"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate5"/><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

My C#

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void SimpleRead(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AZUES-336\\JDOESQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;

            try
            {

                conn.Open();


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn);

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    investigate1.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString;//Presumably where the error is happening
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                if (rdr != null)
                { rdr.Close(); }

                if (conn != null)
                { conn.Close(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

@Seany84
Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default1" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.hexen').after('<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left"></span>')// ui icon

    .keypress(function () {$(this).next('.saveButton').show();}); //adds ui icon

     $('.ui-state-default').hover(
     function () {$(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');},
     function () {$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');}
     ); //ui icon hover

        $('.saveButton').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).prev().attr('id'); //used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call
            var value = $(this).prev().val(); //used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx",
                data: "{Id: " + id + ", Value: " + value + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            $(this).hide();
        }); //runs ajax call and removes ui-icon after .saveButton is clicked

    }); //end .ready
</script> 

<input runat="server" class="hexen" id="investigate1"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate2"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate3"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate4"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate5"/><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.net: Web Forms or Web Pages project?

Comment: I think web forms.. C# ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION

Comment: Can you post your entire ASPX page (editing your original post).. ?

Comment: Ok, I can't see what could be wrong if you used my <asp:TextBox.. control. Probably not the issue, but have you tried Cleaning and/or Rebuilding your solution (by right-clicking on your Solution in the Solution Explorer window) and trying to run it again in debug mode.

Comment: It's still throwing an error.. :|

Comment: Ok, running out of ideas here.. I just noticed you have the line:
investigate1.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString;
Should it not be: investigate1.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(); or was that a typo?

Comment: +1 for EagleEyes.. Well done Seany84, that was my issue. Stupid little markup.. Thanks man, appreciate the guidance

Comment: Hehe, that was my last suggestion. Always the way.. best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an ASP server control instead of a standard HTML input.

Replace,

```
<input runat="server" class="hexen" id="investigate1"/>
```

with

```
<asp:TextBox ID="investigate1" runat="server" CssClass="hexen" />
```

and try it then.

Also, should the line:

```
investigate1.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString;
```

be this instead:

```
investigate1.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

http://www.asp.net have good tutorials for ASP.net web forms, MVC and web pages.

Comment: It's throwing me a "parse" error. `The base class includes the field 'investigate1' but it's type is not compatible with the type of control (textbox)`

Comment: Are there any other controls in your ASPX with an ID of "investigate1"? Also, can you post your entire ASPX markup please.

Answer (score 0):

This is the property you have to use:

[HtmlInputControl.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcontrol.value.aspx)

Html Input with runat="server" attribute are converted into HtmlInputControl. And those don't have a Text property, but a Value property. So change Text for Value.